# How can a dup-closed question be reopened?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

Today there was a question in JavaScript tag, [Difference between function f(){} and f = function(){}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125202/difference-between-function-f-and-f-function/28125251#28125251) which is very similar to a canonical question [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname). But the similarity is only in the title text. The actual problem is different in the new question. The canonical question explains the differences between function declaration and function expression. But the new question doesn't use `var` keyword so the function actually becomes global.

Actually it was dup-closed earlier by a Gold Hammer and I reopened it with mine. Now I went back to that question and found that it was closed by 5 other people as dup.

As it is closed now, search engines may not list that question at the top if somebody else has a similar problem. Since I exhausted my reopen vote for that question, what is the best possible way to get that opened again?

**Edit:** As Jereon suggested, I was thinking about editing the title to make it clear, but I couldn't come up with a clear title.

**Edit 2:** Before posting the question here, I tried to engage one of the [Dup close voters in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21149959#21149959)

Comment: Edit the question so it is clear to others as well that it's about something else in essence. The first step should have been to edit the question's title, at least. Leave a more useful comment that says *why* it is different.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Sorry, I was adding that problem in the question. I couldn't come up with a proper title.

Comment: Would it be correct and equivalent to write `global.f = function(){};` ?  Put that `global.` in the title.

Comment: @BenVoigt `global` is actually applicable to Node.js environment :( This question is not specific to any environment.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Already found the correct syntax on MDN, and edited the title.  Should now be evident that it is not equivalent to the chosen dupe.  Since the code there is using `alert`, it looks like `window.f = ` may also be a valid way to write it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for helping me out. But, `this` need not refer to the global object always. So, technically, it doesn't imply what OP meant.

Comment: @thefourtheye: In the particular case, [it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Global_context).  And it highlights that it is setting a property not declaring a new variable, hence non-dupe.

Comment: @gnat: that one doesn't have answers. The dupe it was closed as doesn't really answer the case where it is already closed. It probably should gain a more general purpose answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt I actually changed it to `Difference between function expression in global scope and function declaration`. Now I am afraid the actual solution is in the title itself :(

Comment: @MartijnPieters per my reading, it was pretty close. And the answer is just in dupe-target over there: to have a solid case for reopening a dupe, question would better have explicit and compelling explanation of the difference from the target. As long as there isn't one, it is always at risk. As soon as there is one, there are plenty ways to challenge closure, starting from plain vote reopen and up to mod flagging and opening meta discussion of a [meta-tag:specific-question]

Comment: @gnat We should not flag mods for this.

Comment: @thefourtheye: The only problem with that title change is it will no longer catch the eye of other users with the same problem.  Solving the problem in the title isn't an issue, if it still gains the attention of future readers.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sadly yes :( But that might keep the dup voters at a distance.

Comment: @thefourtheye who told you so. The only real rule for mod flagging is consider it strictly on a case by case basis. When I can make a compelling flag message in favor of dupe reopen, along with explanation of why I prefer flagging over meta discussion, I do so. And if they find it _indeed_ compelling, moderators do per flag

Comment: @gnat ChrisF is a diamond mod and please check his answer below. That is not recommended at all.

Comment: @thefourtheye that's a good answer and reasoning why one shouldn't _generally_ flag makes good sense. As I wrote above, flagger should "make a compelling flag message in favor of dupe reopen, along with explanation of why I prefer flagging over meta discussion" - if they can't, they better find other way. Side note the point in this answer about taking into account that "moderator who sees the flag isn't guaranteed to be a subject expert" is particularly important, I try to always assume that when flagging

Answer (score 4):

As Jeroen points out in his [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284436/how-can-a-dup-closed-question-be-reopened#comment147145_284436) the way to get a "duplicate" question that isn't reopened is to:

1. Edit it so that it's clear that it's about something else.
2. Vote to reopen.

These will put the question on the reopen queue where others can check it out and vote accordingly.

3. Go to chat and see if you can drum up support that way.
4. Finally, come to meta to post a question here.

What you *shouldn't* do is flag it for moderator attention. The moderator who sees the flag isn't guaranteed to be a subject expert so they aren't in a position to say whether the closing was correct one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't use the suggestion 1 because I couldn't come up with a better title, I couldn't use suggestion 2 because I already used my dup hammer to reopen, before posting the question I already tried the [chat option](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21149959#21149959). And I didn't flag that question at all.

Comment: It's now had 5 reopen votes