# Information in message for 'marked as duplicate' should be clearer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I [encountered an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697008/how-to-get-device-aosp-build-number-in-android-devices-programmatically) that has been marked as a duplicate. However the question is (in my opinion) clearly not a duplicate - the question is about a OS/Android System version number, and the purported duplicate relates to how to get an application version number.

There are also several comments to this effect under the question. I raised a flag to a moderator explaining the problem, but it was declined with reason "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention". A quick review of the profiles of those who marked the page as duplicate indicates that the self-documented skill set of the closers is not in the subject area of the question.

After some research, I found that [I should 'vote to reopen'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284436/how-can-a-dup-closed-question-be-reopened)  (which I couldn't find the link for), and after further research, [found that one needs 3000 rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275186/3063884) in order to see the 'vote to reopen' link.

It seems like this should be an easier process -- e.g. a link to how voting to close/reopen works with the "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." The linked details should explain the process, and also that one needs to have 3000 rep in order to have a chance to vote to re-open.

Without easily accessible details of how to correct a possible problem, a typical user is probably not going to trawl through Meta in order to find a solution, and thus site content is less likely to be improved.

Comment: This is quite unusual, I'd guess that it got exposed in a review queue.  The question as written before you edited it was rather poor, that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not something that a moderator can or should empirically decide, as they may not be well-versed with a language or framework.  That's why your flag was declined.

Since you're short of the required rep, bringing it up on Meta is a good option, since this means you get more eyes looking at the same question - many of which do have the ability to cast reopen votes.

I'm not sure that there needs to be mention of the amount of rep required to cast a reopen vote in *every* closed/on hold question, since that feels more like noise as that info is conveyed in [the privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) itself.

Comment: Also, there's chat, for example the [SO close-vote reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). And the OP gets additional help when his question is closed / a duplicate proposed.

Comment: I fully understand (now) the reason that the moderator would decline the flag. It's unfortunate that other users who have sufficient rep to cast a 'close' vote would do so without understanding the topic content. As for the  mentioning of the 3000 rep, I'm not suggesting that that should happen in the message on the page, but on whatever the proposed link points to. The main point is to give the reader more information about *what can be done* to address a perceived problem.

Comment: Turns out that the question was reopened:  *Post Reopened by CJBS, showdev, Zong Zheng Li, AJFarmar, HaveNoDisplayName 
occurred Sep 17 '15 at 0:01*